Locomotive-scroll don't work in my code in R3F
Locomotive scroll doesn't work in my code. When I click on a 3D element it displays a modal with text and I'd like to add scrolling effects with locomotive, I don't get console errors but scrolling is blocked. I can only use the scroll bar and I don't understand where the problem is coming from. The modal is displayed on an R3F scene.
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
import locomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";

export default function Modal() {

    const scrollRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (scrollRef.current) {
            const scroll = new locomotiveScroll({
                el: scrollRef.current,
                smooth: true
            });
    
            return () => {
                scroll.destroy();
            };
        }
    }, [scrollRef]);

    useEffect(() => {
        /* Close modal */
        $(".close_icon").on("click", function() {
            $(".modal_infos").css("opacity", "0");
            $(".text_modale_div").each(function() { $(this).css("opacity", "0"); });
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(".modal_infos").css("display", "none");
                $(".text_modale_div").each(function() { $(this).css("display", "none"); });
            }, 200);
        });

        return () => {
            $(".close_icon").off("click");
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="modal_infos">
            <div className="modal-scroll-container" ref={scrollRef} data-scroll-container>
                <div className="close_icon" title="Fermer la fenêtre">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="46" height="46" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="1" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" className="icon icon-tabler icons-tabler-outline icon-tabler-x">
                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                        <path d="M18 6l-12 12" />
                        <path d="M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </div>

                <div className="text_modale_div" data-scroll-section>
                    <div className="text_page">
                        <h1 id="title_page" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="3" data-scroll-position="top">
                            Some txt to try
                        </h1>
                        <p id="first_text__page">
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque eum est dolor repellat deleniti commodi debitis blanditiis cumque sed molestias facilis nesciunt cupiditate, quasi porro? Rerum, maiores. Sapiente, quia ducimus!
                        </p>
                        <div id="second_div_text_page">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat quod culpa sit, ad sunt doloribus assumenda voluptates accusamus labore temporibus distinctio. Esse eius est, maiores at aspernatur impedit molestias numquam?
                        </div>

                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed earum aut voluptates natus repellat sit possimus maxime? Earum perspiciatis sit alias, eveniet, recusandae animi esse hic blanditiis fugit unde quos!                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae debitis dolores eligendi neque ex, dolorum sint? Recusandae provident suscipit architecto ad dolorem aliquid, eligendi quisquam culpa corrupti nostrum corporis accusantium.
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="text_modale_div" id="metro_div">
                    <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae debitis dolores eligendi neque ex, dolorum sint? Recusandae provident suscipit architecto ad dolorem aliquid, eligendi quisquam culpa corrupti nostrum corporis accusantium.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


I'd like it to add a locomotive-scroll effect to the div displayed above a scene in R3F.

Maybe you will be interested in this solution?

Thanks for the answer, I'll look into doing it with this.
